# How to code the query function in the implementation of a crud repository

Tags: java, crud

So typically, I have just had a single interface that implements a CrudRepository and put my @Query in there. However, for this I have a DAO class that is the repo and a DAOImpl that implements that repo. So, I have the implement the method I just want to use a query for and return that query as a List of strings. My question is how do I code the part in the implementation to just pass that List of Strings through?

```
public interface DealerDAO {
    /**
     * @return List of Marketing Orgs
     */
    public Map<String, MarketOrg> getMarketStructure();

    @Query(
            value="SELECT DISTINCT ...",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findDealerCode(String marketOrg, String region, String district);
}
```

```
@Service
public class DealerDAOImpl implements DealerDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    public Map<String, MarketOrg> getMarketStructure() {
        HashMap<String, MarketOrg> mktOrgs = new HashMap<String, MarketOrg>();
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT ....");
        List<Object[]> marketEntities = q.getResultList();
        /* Extra code */

        return mktOrgs;
    }


    @Override
    public List<String> findDealerCode(String marketOrg, String region, String district) {
        //This should return something, not null.
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,I do not understand your need entirely but My guess is that you do not want to provide the implementation for the `findDealerCode()` method but still wants to add an implementation for `getMarketStructure()` to return a Map. If so, instead of providing an implementation for the `DealerDAO` interface, if you have java8 compatibility why don't you use a default method implementation in the interface itself. That way you could still extend the CRUD repository, use the default spring implementation and still get what you want to achieve.Like :

```
public interface DealerDAO extends CrudRepository<Obj,Obj> {
    /**
     * @return List of Marketing Orgs
     */
    default public Map<String, MarketOrg> getMarketStructure() {
        HashMap<String, MarketOrg> mktOrgs = new HashMap<String, MarketOrg>();

        /* Extra code */

        return mktOrgs;
    }

    @Query(
            value="SELECT DISTINCT ...",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findDealerCode(String marketOrg, String region, String district);
}
```

but this means that the method cannot access the state of the instance.**Default methods should only be used to delegate calls to other repository methods**. Default methods - by definition - cannot access any state of an instance (as an interface has none). They only can delegate to other interface methods or call static ones of other classes.

or in spring-boot way you could have separate interfaces for these methods , if you need to have the persistance context in the `getMarketStructure()` method . Like :

```
@Repository
public interface DealerDAO extends CrudRepository<Obj,Obj>, DealerRepositoryCustom {
    @Query(
            value="SELECT DISTINCT ...",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findDealerCode(String marketOrg, String region, String district);
}

public interface DealerRepositoryCustom {
   public Map<String, MarketOrg> getMarketStructure();
}
```

then you could have the implementation for the `DealerRepositoryCustom` interface in a class like :

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true) // if you don't plan on modifying
public class DealerCustomRepositoryImpl implements DealerRepositoryCustom {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<String> findDealerCode(String marketOrg, String region, String district) {
        //This should return something, not null.
        return null;
    }
}
```

For reference [read](https://dzone.com/articles/add-custom-functionality-to-a-spring-data-reposito).

Comment: I think I cut out a bit too much code from my getMarketStructure() method when I posted it. The default would almost work, but I can't bring over my persistence annotation nor can I have the nativeQuery like I have it in the getMarketStructure() if I put in the DAO. (Updated the code in my original post)

Comment: But yes, I want to provide the implementation for the getMarketStructure() function, but I don't want to if I don't need to for the findDealerCode() function. I just want the List of Strings from the query.

Comment: If you need to use your entity manager in this method I suggest you have a separate interface for this particular method only and implement it , so that you could still utilise the default crud implementation for the other interface.

Comment: Is there no way to do what I'm asking then? I can't just pass the List of Strings from the query through the implementation?

Comment: Well, instead of trying to figure out what I was doing, I just pulled the query to the Implementation. I did that and then returned the query.getResultList(). So, hopefully this'll work.

Comment: @DevinM I just updated the answer with another approach , check if it will suit your situation or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Huh, that's actually a really clean way to do it. Thank you!

Comment: @DevinM no problem :) .